# JSON parsing No value

Tags: java, android, json

Im not sure whats the error behind this, but im getting an error saying

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for
http://starstrakph.s3.amazonaws.com/12/avatars/1386757806.jpg
```

My JSON are as follows

```
{"id":"12","display_name":"Anne","screen_name":"Anne Curtis","avatar":"http:\/\/starstrakph.s3.amazonaws.com\/12\/avatars\/1386757806.jpg","avatar_source":"http:\/\/www.balita.com\/filipino-superstar-anne-curtis-katulong-ng-pechanga-resort-casino-sa-pagdiriwang-ng-araw-ng-kasarinlan-ng-pilipinas\/"}
```

And my codes are:

```
JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject(result);
                cFeeds.SetPostScreenName(userObj.getString("screen_name"));
                String avatar = userObj.getString(userObj.optString("avatar"));
                cFeeds.SetAvatar(avatar);
```

Should I use JSON array for this? is there any wrong on my code or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis mine isnt, yep thats the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the value of the json object (which is a json `String)` named `avatar` as the name of another json object which obviously doesn't exist.

```
String avatar = userObj.getString(userObj.optString("avatar"));
```

It seems you just want the value of `avatar`, so just get it

```
String avatar = userObj.optString("avatar");
```

Comment: yep that was it, I wonder also why did i put two getString on that one, Silly me. Thanks BTW